# (python) I want to save scraped image in my folder. For example, it looks like 'google.png'

Tags: python

everyone!

I always make a **scraping** code in python.
I have to save these images on my folder, But I have one problem about it.

If I run this code,
it saves 0.png / 1.png / 2.png / 3.png ..... like it.

However, I want to save
(example) google.png / naver.png / ....   (**scraped** url).png

I do not know how I solve the problem now.
Could you give me a hand, please?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjqJn.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoLH8.jpg)

Comment: Do NOT post images of code and text. Paste these in as formatted text.

Comment: Use: browser.save_screenshot("img/"+line+".png")

Answer (score 0):

You're doing this..

```py
for i, line in enumerate(r):
........
 browser.save_screenshot('img' + str(i) + '.png')
```

`i` represents the counter in a loop [i suggest you look into enumerate](https://realpython.com/python-enumerate/). That's why you're getting images with the name `0.png`, `1.png` etc.

This may be what you're looking for:

```py
browser.save_screenshot('img' + line + '.png')
```